# Text only changes for player 2 and not player 1

Tags: roblox

So I typed this script(it's a normal script)to change the text when 2 players are in the game but the problem is when player 2 joins the game any later the text only changes to player 2 and nothing happens to player 1(I inserted the script in the textlabel where the textlabel will change)and when player 1 leaves the game the text does not change.Anyways here's the script:

```
if #game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayers() >= 2 then
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 25"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 24"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 23"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 22"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 21"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 20"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 19"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 18"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 17"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 16"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 15"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 14"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 13"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 12"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 11"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 10"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 9"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 8"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 7"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 6"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 5"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 4"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 3"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 2"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 1"
wait(1)
script.Parent.Text ="Intermission: 0"
else
script.Parent.Text ="Waiting for Players"
end
```

Comment: 1st, a script does not loop/repeat, try adding events in. Also this is abit off topic(sorry), but I would recommend using a for loop for this task, it will save you a lot of time and lines.

Comment: So a localscript is required for guis?

Comment: Yes. Have a normal script detect if 2 players are in the game, then have it trigger an event. In your local script, have it listen for this event, when it hears the event edit the text.

Comment: Also i did use localscript but the problem was when i tested the game with 2 players(2 players needed to join at the same time)The intermission was lagging behind for player 1.

Comment: Did they join at the exact same time or was there a grace period. Also you probably want to wait for the player to loading in, as the script will probably detect the player before the 2nd player's script is loaded in.

Comment: Yeah they joined at the same time(I was testing it in roblox studio).

Comment: I would recommend putting a variable in the main(normal) script, and have that count down in a for loop, with each second would fire the event with this variable. Then in your local script, just detect for the event, and have the `text = "Intermission: " + value`.

Comment: Ok i actually have 1 more question, where do you put the script,event, & localscript?

Comment: localscript should be in the starterplayerscripts folder, events in replicated storage, normal script should be in serverscript service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should fix the error(s)

```
local countdown = 25
local players = 0

game:GetService("Players").PlayerAdded:Connect(function()
    players = players + 1
end)

game:GetService("Players").PlayerRemoving:Connect(function()
    players = players - 1
end)

while wait(1) do
    if players > 1 then
        script.Parent.Text = "Intermission: ".. countdown
        print("Intermission: ".. countdown)
        countdown = countdown - 1
        if countdown <= 0 then
            script.Parent.Visible = false
            countdown = 25
        end
    end
    
    if players < 2 then
        script.Parent.Text = "Intermission: ".. countdown
        print("Intermission: ".. countdown)
        countdown = 25
    end
end
```

Comment: oh um i used events instead but thank you for answering!

Comment: everyone is supposed to post an answer to answer instead of commenting can you mark mine with a check since mine works too and i am the only one that answered properly

Comment: also are you able to answer my question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63642253/roblox-kick-argument-1-missing

Comment: i checked your answer and sorry no im pretty new to scripting...