# Roblox Kick Argument 1 missing

Tags: lua, roblox

i keep getting missing argument 1 when i type my username then type reason then press kick using these scripts below:

**LOCAL**

```
local Replicated = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local reason = script.Parent.Parent.Reason
local player = script.Parent.Parent.Name

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    Replicated.Events.Kick:FireServer(player.Text, reason.Text)
end)
```

**SERVER**

```
local KickPlayer = game.ReplicatedStorage.Events.Kick

KickPlayer.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(Name,Reason)
    game.Players:FindFirstChild(Name):Kick(Reason)
end)
```

EDIT: this will work but not the otherone

```
KickPlayer.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(Name,Reason)
    game.Players:FindFirstChild("username"):Kick(Reason)
end)
```

EDIT2: this gives ServerScriptService.Event_Handler:14: attempt to index nil with 'Kick'

```
KickPlayer.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(Player,Reason)
    game.Players:FindFirstChild(Player):Kick(Reason)
end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the server script with this

```lua
local KickPlayer = game.ReplicatedStorage.Events.Kick

KickPlayer.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(_, Name,Reason) -- "_" is the player instance
    game.Players:FindFirstChild(Name):Kick(Reason)
end)
```

and this is the prototype of "RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent"

```lua
 RBXScriptSignal OnServerEvent ( Instance player , Tuple arguments )
```

Comment: thanks but i already solved it by doing something like that but since your script works too i'll give you the best answer check

Comment: but are you able to help me remove this error when theres no player to kick?
ServerScriptService.Event_Handler:14: attempt to index nil with 'Kick'